# Yubico’s take on U2F wrapping: purpose of MAC?

Tags: hmac

I've been reading up on [Yubico's implementation of U2F](https://www.yubico.com/2014/11/yubicos-u2f-key-wrapping/).

I am confused on the purpose of the message authentication code (MAC). It prevents an attacker from providing a key handle (particularly a nonce) that wasn’t generated by the U2F device. I get that.

**What would an attack involving changing the nonce look like?** Since the AppID is also provided to the U2F device, an attacker having taken control of a website (say site-a.com) wouldn’t be able to do a challenge-response for another website (say site-b.com), even if the attacker knew the user’s nonce for site-b.com.

Comment: Are you assuming that the connection to the service that is ID'd by the AppID is secure? Because otherwise a man-in-the-middle attack might be possible. Note that sometimes a bit of redundancy is build into protocols...

Comment: Not necessarily (U2F spec allows non-HTTPS URLs, and the local traffic between the browser and the U2F device might be tampered with). But even so, I'm not sure what a MITM might be able to achieve. If the attacker knows the nonce of a real account, then it is very likely that the attacker has the associated MAC since they are stored and transmitted together. If the attacker is attempting a nonce brute-force (impractical because the user has to touch the device for each attempt), then trying all nonces should be similarly hard as trying all nonce+MAC pairs.